# Polymer change core-toolbar from tall to normal

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) to redesign my website. I'm having some trouble implementing the [`core-scroll-header-panel`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scroll-header-panel) in combination with the [`core-toolbar`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-toolbar).

My problem is the following: I have a [`core-drawer-panel`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-drawer-panel) on the left that holds a menu throughout my site. On the right side I hav the `core-scroll-header-panel`. Now, on some pages (selected in the `core-drawer-panel`) I want to show a tall header, and on others a small one. So I need a way to toggle the `tall`-attribute of the `core-toolbar`.

To do this I used Polymer's [data-binding](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html) to just change the class of the `core-toolbar`. Unfortunately this doesn't work adequate, as the content in the sidebar is off-position after changing the class. To clarify: if you load the site as a `tall` `core-toolbar`, the content displayed on the right is all offset a little to the bottom. When changing the class to something else than `tall`, this offset remains. Vice versa the same, you can see a working example here: http://jsbin.com/vepoyami/2/edit . In the sample code you can change the `if(this.page == "tall"){` to `small` instead of `tall` to see the effect if it was the other way around. Here's the code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      core-toolbar#navheader{
        background-color: #99182c;
        color: white;
      }
      core-toolbar#mainheader{
        color: white;
        fill: white;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
      core-drawer-panel:not([narrow]) #navicon{
        display: none;
      }
      core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #headerBg {
        background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg);
      }
      core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #condensedHeaderBg {
        background-color: #99182c;
      }
      core-header-panel#drawer{
        background-color: white;
      }
      paper-item.core-selected:not(.noColor){
        color: #99182c;
        fill: #99182c;
      }
      .big-container{
        display:block;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
      <core-header-panel drawer id="drawer" mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar id="navheader">
          <span>Main Title</span>
        </core-toolbar>

        <core-menu selected="{{page}}" valueattr="id" selectedItem="{{pageItem}}">
          <paper-item icon="home" label="Small" id="small"></paper-item>
          <paper-item icon="today" label="Tall" id="tall"></paper-item>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>

      <core-scroll-header-panel main condenses="true" id="headerPanel" keepCondensedHeader>

        <core-toolbar class="{{mainheaderClass}}" id="mainheader">
          <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" on-tap="{{nav}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button id="back" icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
          <div flex></div>
          <paper-menu-button icon="more-vert" halign="right">
            Nothing yet!
          </paper-menu-button>
          <div class="bottom indent title">{{pageItem.label}}</div>
        </core-toolbar>

        <div class="content">
          <core-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" transitions="cross-fade-all" class="main" valueattr="id"> <!-- class main needed? -->
            <section id="small">
              <div class="big-container">
                The header should be a small one that stays there.
                <lorem-ipsum paragraphs="100"></lorem-ipsum>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section id="tall">
              <div class="big-container">
                The header should be a tall one that scrolls down into a small one and stays there.
                <lorem-ipsum paragraphs="100"></lorem-ipsum>
              </div>
            </section>
          </core-animated-pages>
        </div>

        </core-header-panel>

      </core-scroll-drawer-panel>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', {
      ready: function(){
        this.page = 'tall';
      },
      pageChanged: function(){
        if(this.page == "tall"){
          this.mainheaderClass = "tall"
        }else{
          this.mainheaderClass = "";    
        }
      },
      nav: function(){
        this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Presumably this way of toggling it's state is not a good way. On top of the issue I have said, when it is in it's small state, the color isn't filled in.

What have I done wrong here, and how should it be done instead?

**Update:** I submitted a bug on [github](https://github.com/Polymer/core-scroll-header-panel/issues/12#issuecomment-50509947). A collaborator replied that there were still issues with the `core-scroll-header-panel` that some styles weren't reset, and that they are working on a fix hopefully by next release.

The collaborator also added that `.measureHeaderHeight()` can be called to reevaluate the height of the content, as already noted by [Ümit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992190/1319187) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1.) There seem to be some errors in your HTML structure:

You use `core-scroll-header-panel` but you use the wrong closing tag (`core-header-panel`)

2.) Are you sure you want to use a `core-scroll-header-panel` and not a `core-header-panel`. 
This is how it looks if you use a `core-header-panel` instead of a `core-scroll-header-panel` ?

http://jsbin.com/vepoyami/4/edit?html,output

3.) If you use a `core-scroll-header-panel` you probably have to re-calculate the header height. 
This is what the code docs says:

```
/**
   * The height of the header when it is at its full size.
   *
   * By default, the height will be measured when it is ready.  If the height
   * changes later the user needs to either set this value to reflect the
   * new height or invoke `measureHeaderHeight()`.
   *
   * @attribute headerHeight
   * @type number
 */
    headerHeight: 0,
```

You need to this to your `pageChanged` callback:

```
this.async(function() {
    this.$.headerPanel.measureHeaderHeight();
});
```

See here:

http://jsbin.com/vepoyami/7/edit?html,output

Comment: 1. My bad, used to use a `core-header-panel` in my initial design. 2. I'm pretty sure I want the `core-scroll-header-panel` because I want the image to fade to the color. 3. Looks good, but there seem to be some issues. If you scroll halfway on the `tall` page (that the image is semi-colored) and then go to `small` page, the title bar has the same opacity. Also, when scrolling halfway the page then and going back to `tall`, the header starts at full height, yet semi-transparent and already scrolled down in content...

Comment: I can see these issues. I guess `core-scroll-header-panel` doesn't properly support the use-case of switching between tall and small header. You can try to scroll to the top before switching modes. 
However the opacity on condensedBg and headerBg is not reset. See here: 
http://jsbin.com/vepoyami/10/edit?html,output

Comment: That could be possible. This solution is nicer, but still not really satisfying. Another possibility would be to put `core-header-panel`'s and `core-scroll-header-panel`s inside the content. It would perhaps work, but would be a very big workaround with other malfunctions. Not so sure what I should do now...

Comment: I think this could be a bug in `core-scroll-header-panel`. It should properly deal with changing header sizes without needing to scroll to the top. You can create a github issue in the corresponding repository (https://github.com/Polymer/core-scroll-header-panel/issues)

Answer (score 0):

you have to toggle the `fixed` attribute of the `core-scroll-header-panel`.

see this jsbin :

http://jsbin.com/niheguma/1/edit

Comment: I'm afraid the content still isn't lined up properly in your example. Going from tall to small still leaves a major gap between the header and the content on the small page. Other than that, the styling is also not changed, but this seems to be a bug, so only future releases will make this I presume.

Comment: A better way is instead of toggling small and tall you should just use `<core-pages>` and have the small and tall header on different pages.

Comment: @AwesomByte: issue is that I'm using [`<core-animated-pages>`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) to displaymy content, using the `cross-fade-all` transition and alternatively the `slide-from-right` transition. Including the header in this would also cause the header to be transitioned

Comment: Don't you want the header to be transitioned?

Comment: From tall to small yes, but I have a multitude of pages where the header stays small. Switching between these pages using this method would result in the header itself to fade/slide

Comment: wrap your content in `core-animated-pages`, and your `core-scroll-header-panel` in `core-pages`. when a menu item is selected, change both the `core-pages.selected` and the `core-animated-pages.selected` `core-pages will not have any transition effect, just switch between the two.

Comment: I like the idea, but AFAIK the page structure should be that the content is contained inside the `core-scroll-header-panel` or `core-header-panel`, as can be seen in the source code of [this example](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scroll-header-panel/demo.html). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the content is inside the `*-header-panel`.  my idea still works that way. the page structure is like this. `core-pages -> core-scroll-header-panel -> core-animated-pages ->` _content_

Comment: Could you perhaps make a quick draft? I'm a bit confused - you say I should also apply the `core-pages.selected`, but this would imply for each `core-pages` I have x-amount of `<section>`'s, each containing a `*-header-panel`, all containing `core-animated-pages` all containing again x-sections..

Comment: just one core-pages. then x amount of sections in core-pages is how many pages you have. i discovered a much more efficient way to do it. JSFiddle coming up